# MySQL - searching multiple schemas for particular value

Tags: mysql

I have a server with multiple schemas. I need to find specyfic email address. Every schema looks pretty much te same, they have same structure. What i wanted to do is to write a script to for displaying dbname and specyfic data related to given email . Heres my script, but it do not work:(

```
DELIMITER $$

#Drop procedure if exists SearchAllDb $$
Create procedure SearchAllDb()

BEGIN
DECLARE DB_NAME Varchar(50);
DECLARE done INT default FALSE;
DECLARE CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES CURSOR FOR
SELECT schema_name from information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name like 'itools_%';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES;

myloop: LOOP
FETCH CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES INTO DB_NAME; 

IF done THEN LEAVE myloop;
END IF; 

WHILE done != TRUE DO

SET @SQL = CONCAT('select DB_NAME, id, sn, name, email 
from',DB_NAME,'.`open_cases` where email like 'xxx@yahoo.com'');
prepare stmt from @SQL;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

END WHILE; 

CLOSE CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES; 
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

I have something similar written in t-sql and it works...

```
DECLARE @DB_NAME VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE name like 'pickup-%' and name!= 'pickup-stored';

OPEN CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES;
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME 

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
Print @DB_NAME;
exec ('select '''+ @DB_NAME + ''' as db, id, sn, email from ['+ 
@DB_NAME+'].dbo.requests where email in (''xxx@live.com'')');

FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME 
END

CLOSE CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_ALL_DB_NAMES;
```

Comment: How is it possible `open_cases` table exists in every database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, *doesn't work* is not enough information to help you. Please [edit] your question to tell us more.  **Pro tip** stored procedures are quite hard to debug. You may want to work through your logic in a command-line client first.

Comment: Open cases it's a name of table so it can have same name for every single database

Comment: To be more specyfic. I would like to perform select on all my databases and view the result with indication on which database the record were found.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were doing fine up until you introduced the WHILE.

1. THE WHILE is redundant since you are using a LOOP, you should remove those lines.
2. The LOOP doesn't have an END.
3. The CONCAT statement will treat the first use of DB_NAME as one of your column names and there are some quoting issues with the LIKE.
4. The ';' at the end of the procedure should  be '$$' which you have specified as your DELIMITER.

I've taken a few liberties with your variable names but this tidied up version should illustrate the points.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SearchAllDb $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAllDb()
BEGIN
  DECLARE db_name VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT schema_name 
    FROM information_schema.schemata
    WHERE schema_name LIKE 'itools_%';

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  myloop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO db_name; 

    IF done THEN 
      LEAVE myloop;
    END IF; 

    SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT ''', db_name, ''', id, sn, name, email 
      FROM `', db_name,'`.`open_cases` 
      WHERE email LIKE ''xxx@yahoo.com''');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  END LOOP; 

  CLOSE cur; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

There's a very good CURSOR example in the documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html which will help you with the structure of the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works like charm:) For anyone who want to use it, feel free. This particular script is used to search for the value across all schemas/databases across instance.

Comment: @PiotrZima That goes without saying, anything you post to the site can be used by anyone. You should take a look at 'Content Permissions, Restrictions, and Creative Commons Licensing' from the terms of service for the site https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing.